# How can I use my own data with TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have data set like this

```
2016-10-24,23.00,15.47,76.00,1015.40,0.00,0.00,100.00,26.00,100.00,100.00,0.00,6.88,186.01,12.26,220.24,27.60,262.50,14.04,2.1
2016-10-24,22.00,16.14,73.00,1014.70,0.00,0.00,10.20,34.00,0.00,2.00,0.00,6.49,176.82,11.97,201.16,24.27,249.15,7.92,0.669999 
....
....
```

This size is [n][20] and format of this file is CSV. Also "n" is unknown. How can I import and use this data in with Tensorflow, in Python (Like: split train and test data).

I already looked https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#reading-data. However, still I can't import this file in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the standard library module `csv`

```
import csv
with open('yourfile.csv', newline='') as f:
   r = csv.reader(f)
   for row in r:
       print(row) #Each row is a list of the values in a line of your file
                  #All you have to do then is process them in tensorflow
```

Comment: thank you, I imported this file using this. Also, I will try use this in Tensorflow, then I will give feedback because I am not sure that I can use this in Tensorflow. :)

Comment: @Estel what exactly was your problem with the way presented on the tensorflow site?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas library.

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None,index_col=0)
print a
```

and transform int to numpy array (if you want) with

```
a.values
```